# Unable to perform requests in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, cheerio

I have some code like this:-

```
const request=require('request');
const url=require('url');
const cheerio=require('cheerio');

request({uri: 'https://www.facebook.com/'}, (err, resp, body)=>{
    var $=cheerio.load(body);
    console.log($('title').text());
    console.log($('body').text())
});
```

When I try to request to facebook or google the response returned is something like:-

```
Facebook - ??? ??? ?????? | Facebook
??????? login or signup ??????? ??
```

or

```
Google
Signin??? ???....
```

How can I solve these question marks?

Comment: I copied your code and could not reproduce the error. It worked fine. Ensure you update all the packages.

Comment: @marshy101 #metoo

Comment: I have another problem as well. When I request Facebook then Facebook sends response in regional language rather than original language. Looks like I reveal my location while requesting.How can I solve that

Comment: If you want hide your location when making request you should use a VPN. Some VPNs allow you to choose which country you are making the request from.

Comment: I have one more problem. When I try to request to website the website gave me browser update response.. How can I solve that? I think I can solve it using HTTP headers how can I do that?

Comment: I got the same message when trying to request Facebook. Apparently, they maybe blocking certain crawlers such as `request`. If you try other websites such as Google it will work. The only way around it is to try using another crawler. There is puppeteer and a few others out there.

Comment: So what can be the solution? Is there any other library to do that. I am researching for the solution

Comment: There are other headless browser like zombie, Phantom js. Please provide me practical solution for this other then puppeteer module, marshy.

Comment: I heared about one more powerful framework nightmare.js. can you gave me some code practical regarding this. How can I get the whole code using this library.