# How to add a subdomain to a URL string in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to add a subdomain to a URL string in NodeJS, specificaly `www`. but only if the URL doesn't already have a one.

Examples of inputs :

```
# changes
https://facebook.com/
facebook.com

# doesn't change
https://developers.facebook.com/
```

Their outputs :

```
# changes
https://www.facebook.com/
www.facebook.com

# doesn't change
https://developers.facebook.com/
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it by finding number of dots in URL, if they are more than 1 then `www` can be applied.

```js
let url = "https://facebook.com/";
url = getURL(url);
console.log(url);

console.log(getURL("sbc.someurl.com/sometopic/hello.world"));


function getURL(url){

url = url.split("//");
let isHttps = url.length > 1 ? url[0] : false;
if(url && url.length > 1){
  url = url[1]; // someurl.com/sometopic/hello.world
}
else{
  url = url[0];
}

let a = url.split("/");
let u = a[0]; // someurl.com


let arr = u.split(".");
if(arr.length > 2){
  console.log("No need for www");
}
else{
    a[0] = "www." + a[0]; 
}

if(isHttps){
  return isHttps + "//" +  a.join("/");
}
else{
  return a.join("/");
}

}
```

Comment: But if url is like https://someurl.com/sometopic/hello.world, then number of dot is two or in sone case it can be more.

Comment: even accepted solution will fail for this kind of case.

Comment: Nice efforts.I like it.

Comment: All answers are correct friends. Please see this also'-.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58750335/unable-to-perform-requests-in-node-js

Comment: Let me check it.